# Why is it that an even degree polynomial with real coefficients has positive and negative complex roots?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

This seems very obvious but I can't get my head around why/prove it to myself

So, given that a root of $$x^6 + (2-k)x^4 + (25-2k)x^2 - 25k = 0$$
is $x = \sqrt2 + \sqrt3\,i$, I need to find the other $5$ roots.

Obviously, one other root is the conjugate of the given one, but apparently, since the degree of the polynomial is even ($6$) then the other roots are $-x$ and $-x^*$ (where $x$ is the given root and $x^*$ is its conjugate)

I know how to find the other $2$ roots, but I just can't wrap my head around why the other roots are $-x$ and $-x^*$ *because* it's an even degree polynomial?

Comment: I see that if you have 1 complex root, you can get its conjugate and using the property p(x)=p(-x) we can get 2 more roots, this is a total of 4 roots. Of course manual multiplication is rather painful. How did you get the remaining 2 roots?

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial you gave is of the form $f(x^2)$. Therefore, if $a$ is a root then so is $-a$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not just because the *degree* is even, but because the whole polynomial is even, i.e. $p(-x) = p(x)$ (since there are only even powers of $x$ in there).

Hence, if $p(\alpha) = 0$, then $p(-\alpha) = 0$ as well.

Comment: That makes so much sense! thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can factor directly "by visual inspection" as $$(x^2-k)(x^4+2x^2+25)=0,$$ and the biquadratic can be further factored with real coefficients by quadratic completion from the "wrong" end,
$$
x^4+2x^2+25=(x^2+5)^2-10x^2+2x^2=(x^2+2\sqrt2 x+5)(x^2-2\sqrt2 x+5)
$$
so that this factor alone is responsible for all sign variants of $x=\pm\sqrt2\pm i\sqrt3$.

Comment: Not many people can see this answer! Clever!