# Even degree rational polynomials must attain some rational values twice?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

If $P$ is a polynomial, with rational coefficients and of even degree, do there exist arbitrarily large rational $y$ such that $P(x)=y$ has two roots in the rationals?

The tricky bit, I suppose, is to show that polynomials without an axis of symmetry, which cannot be described as $Q(ax^2+bx+c)$, fit this criterion. But I have no idea if it is true at all.

Comment: Is a rational polynomial a polynomial of rational coefficients or what does it mean?

Comment: yes, with rational coefficients

Comment: How do you know *any* such $y$ exists?

Comment: That's what I'm asking, whether $y$ does exist.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027237/why-is-it-that-an-even-degree-polynomial-with-real-coefficients-has-positive-and

Comment: See also: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27229/polynomials-with-rational-coefficients/27231

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think the question is an easy one, and I don't have an answer, but I suspect the answer is "no, not necessarily".

As a test case, consider the polynomial

$$P(x) = x^4 + 2x\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\,$$

Based on limited testing, I don't think there is *any* rational number $y$ such that $P(x) = y$ has more than one rational root.

To prove the statement

\begin{align*}
&\text{There is no rational number}\;y\;\text{such that the equation}
\qquad\;\;\;\;\;\\[4pt]
&\qquad P(x) = y\\[4pt]
&\text{has more then one rational root}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

it would suffice to prove the statement

\begin{align*}
&\text{There is no rational number}\;a\;\text{such that the polynomial}\qquad\;\;\,\\[4pt]
&\qquad Q(x) = \frac{P(x)-P(a)}{x-a}\\[4pt]
&\text{has a rational root}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Thus, for the case $P(x) = x^4 + 2x$, after dividing out the common factor of $(x-a)$, we get

$$Q(x) = x^3+ax^2+a^2x+(a^3+2)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\,$$
So perhaps continue by trying to prove that there is no rational number $a$ such that the cubic polynomial $Q(x)$, as defined above, has a rational root.

Comment: You're looking for rational points on the elliptic curve $x^3 + a x^2 + a^2 x + (a^3 + 2)$.  According to Maple, this has Weierstrass form $t^2 + s^3 + 16$. If I read [this LMFDB page](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/432/e/3) correctly, there are no rational points.

Comment: @Robert Israel: Nice interpretation in terms of rational points on an elliptic curve. So if your conclusion is correct, that would confirm my guess that the answer to the OP's question is "no, not necessarily".